# How to add double quotes to the xml tag attributes that is a string content

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an xml string content, before parsing it, I want to add double quotes to the tag attributes so that it will be valid xml:

```
"<fields>
<f id=page-number>OP</f>
<f id=presenter>MA</f>
<f id=title>OPENER</f>
<f id=type>CLIP</f>
<f id=graphic></f>
<f id=video-id></f>
<f id=audiochannel></f>
<f id=event-status></f>
<f id=audio-time uec>26</f>
<f id=back-time uec>@41410</f>
<f id=editor></f>
<f id=total-time>26</f>
<f id=cume-time></f>
<f id=still-id></f>
<f id=app1-1>SF</f>
<f id=var-3></f>
<f id=modify-by>scrivensl</f>
<f id=modify-date>1571272301</f>
<f id=status>OK</f>
<f id=app3-1></f>
<f id=air-date>1571272300</f>
</fields>"

List<string> patternList = new List<string>() {    @"<fields[^>]*>([\s\S]*)</fields>"};
foreach (var item in patternList)
{
  matchedContent = getContent(item, xmlData);
  XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse(matchedContent);
}
```

I want to add double quotes to the tag attributes before parsing, code is still pending for that.

```
public string getContent(string patternToMatch, string content)
{
   // Instantiate the regular expression object.
    Regex r = new Regex(patternToMatch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     return r.Match(content).ToString();
}
```

Comment: it is not a xml string, the values do not have quotes.

Comment: It looks like XML, but not the exact XML, that's what I want, before parsing it to an XML parser I want to add doubles quotes to the id attribute. So that it won't through exception.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use regex for this

Comment: Can you maybe use HtmlAgilityPack? It can handle malformed (x)html and output corrected text. Maybe it can handle "sort of xml"?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing "HtmlAgilityPack" let me try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is not HTML, but still [HtmAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) can be used to normalize it.

```
var orgxml = @"<fields>
<f id=page-number>OP</f>
...
<f id=app3-1></f>
<f id=air-date>1571272300</f>
</fields>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(orgxml);

string cleanxml;
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    doc.Save(sw);
    cleanxml = sw.ToString();
}
```

The `cleanxml` now contains

```xml
<fields>
<f id="page-number">OP</f>
...
<f id="app3-1"></f>
<f id="air-date">1571272300</f>
</fields>
```